# How to ignore @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()") annotation in Unit Test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, junit

I wrote test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@WebAppConfiguration
@Transactional
public class ProfileTest {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Autowired
private ProfileService profileService;

@Autowired
private InterestService interestService;

private SiteUser[] users = {
        new SiteUser("test1@testing.com", "testPass"),
        new SiteUser("test2@testing.com", "testPass"),
        new SiteUser("test3@testing.com", "testPass"),
};

private String[][] interests = {
        {"music", "guitar_xxxxxx", "plants"},
        {"music", "music", "philosophy_19"},
        {"random", "football"},
};

@Test
public void testInterests() {
    
    for(int i=0; i<users.length; i++) {
        SiteUser user = users[i];
        String[] interestArray = interests[i];
        
        userService.register(user);
        
        HashSet<Interest> interestSet = new HashSet<>();
        
        for(String interestText : interestArray) {
            Interest interest = interestService.createIfNotExists(interestText);
            interestSet.add(interest);
            
            assertNotNull("interest should not be null", interest);
            assertNotNull("Interest should have ID", interest.getId());
            assertEquals("Text should match", interestText, interest.getName());
        }
        
        Profile profile = new Profile(user);
        profile.setInterests(interestSet);
        profileService.save(profile); // ERROR 1
        
        Profile retrievedProfile = profileService.getUserProfile(user); // ERROR 2
        
        assertEquals("Interest sets should match", interestSet, retrievedProfile.getInterests());
    }
}

}
```

But this error happens on lines that have comments **ERROR 1** and **ERROR 2** and I found out why is that happening however I don't know how to fix it or if there's any workaround.

Problem is in here:

```
@Service
public class ProfileService {

@Autowired
ProfileDao profileDao;

@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()") // ERROR 1
public void save(Profile profile) {
    profileDao.save(profile);
}

@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()") // ERROR 2
public Profile getUserProfile(SiteUser user) {
    return profileDao.findByUser(user);
}
}
```

These '@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")' annotations are causing the problem, because when I try to use those two methods in my UnitTest, I'm getting this exception: *(AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext)*:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.credentialsNotFound(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:379)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:223)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:65)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
at com.socialnetwork.service.ProfileService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$22c09751.save(<generated>)
at com.socialnetwork.tests.ProfileTest.testInterests(ProfileTest.java:72)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

And if I remove these annotations, my test passes. So do you know how can I fix my tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to skip those annotations? did you tried @WithMockUser to have a mocked user as part of your context?

[Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/test-method.html) you have how to use that annotation.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my problem - all I had to do was to add '@WithMockUser' annotation over my 'testInterests()' method. (And in order to use @WithMockUser annotation I had to add 'spring-security-test' dependency to my pom.xml.